# When I press the edit button, I cannot enter text

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

```
                <TableContainer ml="40px">
                  <Table variant="simple">
                    <Tfoot>
                      <Tr>
                        <Th>name</Th>
                        <Th>
                          {isEditing && editableActor === actor ? (
                            <Input
                              type="text"
                              value={editableActor.name}
                              onChange={handleInputChange}
                              name="name"
                            />
                          ) : (
                            <Text isTruncated> {truncateText(actor.name, 10)}</Text>
                          )}
                        </Th>
                      </Tr>
                      <Tr>
                        <Th>department</Th>
                        <Th>
                          {isEditing && editableActor === actor ? (
                            <Input
                              type="text"
                              value={editableActor.department}
                              onChange={handleInputChange}
                              name="department"
                            />
                          ) : (
                            <Text isTruncated> {truncateText(actor.department, 8)}</Text>
                          )}
                        </Th>
                      </Tr>
                      <Tr>
                        <Th>introduction</Th>
                        <Th>
                          {isEditing && editableActor === actor ? (
                            <Input
                              type="text"
                              value={editableActor.introduction}
                              onChange={handleInputChange}
                              name="introduction"
                            />
                          ) : (
                            <Text isTruncated>{truncateText(actor.introduction, 8)}</Text>
                          )}
                        </Th>
                      </Tr>
                    </Tfoot>
                  </Table>
                </TableContainer>

                <Box mt="60px">
                  {isEditing && editableActor === actor ? (
                    <>
                      <Button ml="20px" mr="10px" onClick={handleSave}>
                        Save
                      </Button>
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <Button ml="20px" mr="10px" onClick={() => handleEdit(actor)}>
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </Box>
              </Flex>
            </Box>
```

Here, when the edit button is pressed, the edit mode is changed to input, but the edit mode is released when text is entered.

```
    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      setEditableActor((prevActor) => ({ ...prevActor, [name]: value }));
    };
    const handleEdit = (actor) => {
      setEditableActor(actor);
      setIsEditing(true); 
    };
```

The rest of the variables or functions work fine when used elsewhere, but I think these two variables are the problem.
please help me..

I asked chat GPT if there was a problem with the source code, and he said there was no problem. It's also not an api problem.